# How can I run Windows command prompt NOT as an administrator from an administrator account?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I have only one user account on my Windows 10, and it is an administrator account. I need to execute a script with cmd.exe, but the command I need to run will throw an error if I run it in an admin shell. However since my account is an administrator, the command prompt will always be open with admin privileges. How can I open a normal shell from my admin account?

I'm aware that a simple solution would be to create a standard user and use that account, however I'd like to avoid that if possible. Is there another way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Even if you are an administrator I guess commands run by default with standard user privileges unless you are the Administrator (Build-in account). But you can still create a scheduled task in Task scheduler and set it to run with low priority and set it to run your script.

Comment: @RicardoBohner when I open cmd.exe, it's open as administrator. It doesn't ask me anything, it's like that as default. I'm not sure if I changed some options in the past to make it so, I don't remember. Is that not the default behavior?

Comment: No that is not the default behaviour. You may have disabled the User Access Control (UAC) but you can easily reenable it: https://articulate.com/support/article/how-to-turn-user-account-control-on-or-off-in-windows-10

Comment: @RicardoBohner Yes, that was it. Thank you.